# Could anyone with MySQLi experience help me with this short SELECT code?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have researched my question but there just isn't much help out there for MySQLI functions. I'm also new here so, please bear with me.

I have a test database named "website" and it contains a table called "users" which has data for all of the members of my website. In a separate file I have the php code that connects to my localhost and selects the database "website." I'm using the newest functions of MySQL so instead of the connection string containing mysql_connect it contains mysqli_connect. The registration process works great and I can find no error in any of the other code that uses the mysqli functions.

My include file (connect.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "useracc", "useracc1", "website");
?>
```

I set up a test script for the login section.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$user = $_POST['user'];
$query = "SELECT birthday FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("RESULT ERROR");

echo "$user";
echo "$result";
?>
```

There is a password box on the previous page but for the test script I left that out and so far, only the $user is shown on the page. I get no error even when I replace "RESULT ERROR" with `mysqli_error($link)`. I've tried interchanging ' for " in every part of the code that uses quotes but that didn't work. I've tried rewording the $query line but that also had no effect. I'm really new to MySQL and php so if you guys could tell me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks for reading my question. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the connect.php after you connect line

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Can't connect Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit;
}
```

this will ensure the connection is made without any errors and return them if there are ...

Comment: It still fails to show an error code and now the page is entirely blank instead of just showing the username. Sorry for being such a noob at this.

Comment: and all you have is the 2 simple files above ?

Comment: I have a homepage that has the form with two text boxes "user" and "pass" The submit button hands the data to login.php, the page above, and the include is included in the code on the login.php page. connect.php is the same include I use to register accounts, which works fine. That's why I'm so confused.

All in all, I have The homepage, connect.php, register.php, and login.php (The code above)

Comment: Thanks for the information. It turns out I didn't have all of the code I needed. I'm still learning. I'm sorry to have bothered you with a noobish question but I do thank you for taking the time to respond.